# Trying to upload files to a database using a class method

Tags: php, class, upload

I'm trying to upload image files to a database using a method inside a class. It should work like a function.

I have 2 php files. The first one, the file that receives the image and calls the method:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)){
    require_once('masterclass.php');

    $galeria = $_POST['gal'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $titulo = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    $mc = new masterclass;
    $mc->saveImage($galeria, $fecha, $titulo, $imagen, 800, 600, 80);
}
?>
```

The second one, the method that should do the job:

```
public function saveImage($galeria, $fecha, $titulo, $tmpImagen, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $quality){
    if( isset($galeria, $fecha, $titulo, $tmpImagen, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $quality) ){
        $ms->dbc(true); // connect to database

        $fecha = $this->formatFecha($fecha); // format date string

        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpImagen);
        $x = imagesx($origen);
        $y = imagesy($origen);

        if( $x > $maxWidth ){
            $nx = $maxWidth;
            $ny = $y*$nx/$x;
        }
        if( $y > $maxHeight ){
            $ny = $maxHeight;
            $nx = $x*$ny/$y;
        }
        else{
            $nx = $x;
            $ny = $y;
        }

        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nx,$ny);
        imagecopyresized($destino,$origen,0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$x,$y);
        imagejpeg($destino, $tmpImagen, $quality);
        $imagen = addslashes(fread(fopen($tmpImagen, "rb"), filesize($tmpImagen)));

        $peticion = "insert into galeria_fotos (galeria, fecha, titulo, imagen) values ('$galeria', '$fecha', '$titulo', '$imagen')";
        mysql_query($peticion) or die($this->isError(2));

        $ms->dbc(false); // disconnect from database
     }
     else{
        die($this->isError(2));
    }
}
```

If I do the method's job directly in the first php file it works. But it doesn't when I use saveImage() from the class.
I'm working since the last year only with JavaScript and I'm cold with PHP.

Sorry for the variable names in spanish, but I think that is totally understandable.

As additional information I can say that I tried sending directly the `$_FILES` array when calling the method, with no results.

Hope you can help me. Thank you all. Regards :)

Comment: Hi, this calls for basic debugging. Where exactly does it fail? I notice you start the function with `isset($galeria,...` is that condition ever fulfilled, ie. is every parameter set?

Comment: @TFennis, that scared me, I'm a unskilled php developer and my english is limited (and i'm here, trying to get help), but your comment does not help me. Thank you anyway...

Comment: @Pekka
I'm using the jquery uploadify plugin to send the image files to the php and I can't get debug information. I'm sending the seven parameters, I'm sure because if I do the job directly in the first php It works pefectly.

sending seven parameters:
`$mc->saveImage($galeria, $fecha, $titulo, $imagen, 800, 600, 80);`

getting seven too:
`isset($galeria, $fecha, $titulo, $tmpImagen, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $quality)`

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you checked out what the request returns (using Firebug, or  "Inspect element" in Chrome for example, and going to the "Net" tab when the upload is triggered) there may be a PHP error message in the response body

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't get debug information". Can't you write to the error log to see what's happening inside the saveImage function?

Comment: No way to get info with jquery uploadify plugin. Net tab is empty -.-"

Comment: Ouch! You rock, @SomeSillyName. And I'm really idiot for no think on that -.-""

I got two "Undefined index" in some lines. I'm feel like a newbie :)
I will take a look. Be right back

Comment: Finally.. The problem is the uploadify version, that changes its nomenclature for some methods in this new version and I was using a code from previous one that I had in other similar script.
  Thank you all again for your time, really :)

Comment: (he's off to read a book called `Happy Path`)

Comment: It isn't exactly a happy path... So you are not wrong entirely ;p
I appreciate your comment anyway, thank you.  Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue. However, I couldn't. I made some changes to my world but I believed to cover everything you posted.

Follow my example:

index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post>
        <input type="file" id="f_up" name="f_up">
        <input type="submit" value=go>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
require_once('masterclass.php');
if (!empty($_FILES)){
    require_once('masterclass.php');

    $galeria = $_POST['gal'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $titulo = $_FILES['f_up']['name'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['f_up']['tmp_name'];

    $mc = new masterclass;
    $mc->saveImage($imagen, 800, 600, 80);
}
```

masterclass.php

```
<?php
class masterclass{
    public function saveImage($tmpImagen, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $quality){
        $db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root') or die('could not connect');
        mysql_select_db('examples',$db);
        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpImagen);
        if( isset($tmpImagen, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $quality) ){

            //$fecha = $this->formatFecha($fecha); // format date string

            $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpImagen);
            $x = imagesx($origen);
            $y = imagesy($origen);

            if( $x > $maxWidth ){
                $nx = $maxWidth;
                $ny = $y*$nx/$x;
            }
            if( $y > $maxHeight ){
                $ny = $maxHeight;
                $nx = $x*$ny/$y;
            }
            else{
                $nx = $x;
                $ny = $y;
            }

            $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nx,$ny);
            imagecopyresized($destino,$origen,0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$x,$y);
            imagejpeg($destino, $tmpImagen, $quality);
            $imagen = addslashes(fread(fopen($tmpImagen, "rb"), filesize($tmpImagen)));

            $peticion = "insert into upload_image (image) values ('$imagen')";
            mysql_query($peticion,$db) or die('error');


        }
        else{
            die($this->isError(2));
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine on mysql 5.5.27 and PHP 5.3.15. Let us know a little more about your environment.